# Cross browser text area for chat

Tags: jquery

I need an cross browser text area for web chat that support HTML . Can we create it with jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

The support of HTML is the tricky part. Not only will it be difficult to implement, it is also a huge security risk.

Anyway, I suggest that you have a look at a WYSIWYG editor like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). It may already have what you are looking for (platform independent, ajax enabled, rich text).